# How to specify error message using bootstrap validator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, message

i am using [1000hz bootstrap validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) to validate my form. I want each error will has it own error message. For example :

```
<input type="text" pattern="^([_A-z0-9]){3,}$" maxlength="20" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="1000hz" required>
```

When no input, it has to display message "The input Twistter is required". If they input value but does not match the PATTERN then it must display message "The Input Twistter is not correct format".

I must be the one who define the messages.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no answer. I read the source code of 1000hz and i found that it use native message from browser. You can define your own validator but there are many messages will be shown. I change to use [parsleyjs](http://parsleyjs.org/) and now everything is ok.

Answer (score 2):

with the 
    data-error=""
atribute you'll be able to specify an error.

for example: <
 input type=text class="form-control" id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="username_text" required data-error="text_field_empty_text" data-minlength="5" />

it will display "text_field_empty_text" either if its empty, or if it has less than 5 characters, i am not aware of how to manage several validations per field, (as in different errors for different rules)

Comment: Apparently this is not possible, according to the developer: "All of the built-in validators need data-native-error="Your error here" due to the way the plugin piggybacks off of the browser's validators. Unfortunately this means you can't deal with specific error messages for multiple built-in validators on the same field, but the only way around it is to reimplement all of these validators individually in the plugin which I'm hesitant to do because of the bloat it would add." https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/210#issuecomment-145031639